# NSDateFormatter Corruption

Tags: nsstring, timezone, nsdate, nsdateformatter, date-format

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";
NSTimeZone *gmt = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:gmt];

NSString* fileTime = [infoArray objectAtIndex:5];
NSDate* sessionStartDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:fileTime];
NSLog(@"%@", [infoArray objectAtIndex:5]);
NSLog(@"%@", sessionStartDate);
```

The two NSLogs:

```
2013-07-17 01:28:50
2013-07-17 05:28:50 +0000
```

Two should be the same, but not.  The hour shows up differently. I did try 'hh' instead of uppercase, but same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your system timezone is not GMT, while NSDateFormatter parses the date string w.r.t `GMT` (you have time zone missing in date string, so it assumes time zone to be GMT).

So what you get is the GMT time from time string converted to your local time.

Use

```
  NSTimeZone *gmt = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT"];
```

and you will get both the date same.